# Views AJAX not work in block node.tpl

Tags: views, ajax

i have some block with sorting exposed filter on region "tab" and i show his in node.tpl like this:

```
print render(block_get_blocks_by_region('tab'));
```

In my block i not have any problem with AJAX in paginator. But my sorting exposed filter not work at all.

After several hours testing i figured out what my block works ( AJAX sorting filter + paginator) if i show his in any another region on page.tpl.

That things i see in header, if show his through any region on page.tpl:

> "better_exposed_filters":{"datepicker":false,"slider":false,"settings":[]},"views":{"ajax_path":"/views/ajax","ajaxViews":{"views_dom_id:7ff6de2549b84f9553122b84f32d822b":{"view_name":"person_books","view_display_id":"block_1","view_args":"61/61","view_path":"node/61","view_base_path":null,"view_dom_id":"7ff6de2549b84f9553122b84f32d822b","pager_element":"0"}}}

That things i see in header, if show his through region "tab" in node.tpl:

> "better_exposed_filters":{"datepicker":false,"slider":false,"settings":[]},"views":{"ajax_path":"/views/ajax","ajaxViews":{"views_dom_id:21d228e5cc07884c39ecda6d29b417c4":{"view_name":"person_books","view_display_id":"block_1","view_args":"61/61","view_path":"node/61","view_base_path":null,"view_dom_id":"21d228e5cc07884c39ecda6d29b417c4","pager_element":"0"},"views_dom_id:a94bccf7913b478becb33a3a27ec903d":{"view_name":"person_books","view_display_id":"block_1","view_args":"61/61","view_path":"node/61","view_base_path":null,"view_dom_id":"a94bccf7913b478becb33a3a27ec903d","pager_element":"0"},"views_dom_id:da94f68eea44bf9ead4034e965977935":{"view_name":"person_books","view_display_id":"block_1","view_args":"61/61","view_path":"node/61","view_base_path":null,"view_dom_id":"da94f68eea44bf9ead4034e965977935","pager_element":"0"}}}

How can i fix it? Why views send many view_dom_id in header if i show my block through region in node.tpl?

P.S. i tryed show views through views_embed_view in node.tpl - same things, not helped me :/

Answer (score 0):

fixed... always, REMEMBER!! always shutdown block in block UI. if not do it, this piece of shit gives something like:

> {"view_name":"person_books","view_display_id":"block_1","view_args":"61/61","view_path":"node/61","view_base_path":null,"view_dom_id":"a94bccf7913b478becb33a3a27ec903d","pager_element":"0"}

in page header and your ajax may work not so clear :)